# Ajax fadein ipcam pictures (smooth crossover)

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadein, fadeout

I really do need your help. Unfortunately my scripting skills are very limitated. I am running a soccer blog and we've just installed our ip-camera. I got everything working except one littlie thing: I would like to have smooth picture crossovers like on this webpage:
http://www.blickpunkt-muenster.de/webcams/webcam-6.php

I've solved the embedding via an ajax request but i cannot get the fadeIn function to work properly though I have googled a lot.
Hopefully you can help me. Would be awesome!!!

my blog: http://bwa-blog.de/bwacam/

my Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                window.setInterval(function () {
                    var path = 'http://bwa-blog.de/bwacam2/ipcam.jpg?' + (new Date()).getTime();
                    $('#demo').attr('src', path);
                }, 10000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="demo" src="http://bwa-blog.de/bwacam2/ipcam.jpg"/>
    </body>
```

Comment: If you want smooth transitions from one image to the next you will have to work with two separate elements. Try work that out with regular fade animations. Changing the src will always instantly change the picture upon download. So first load a image in an element then another in another element and on that load fade the old one out and the new one in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I tested the script from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386374/jquery-cross-fading-two-images-on-a-loop (last post)
The problem is that I do not know how to call the actual picture. The cript loads the picture and then starts the slideshow instead of adding the new picture to the slideshow...

Answer (score 0):

made it. The only thing is that the first refresh is not an overlay but an total fade out and fade in. If anybody knows how to fix that Id be happy as duck :)

```js
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/
     $(function () {
                window.setInterval(function () {
                    var path = 'http://bwa-blog.de/bwacam2/ipcam.jpg?' + (new Date()).getTime();
                    $('#demo').attr('src', path);
                }, 10000);
            });/*]]>*/
                 </script>

    <script> /*<![CDATA[*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".featured > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() {
        $('.featured > div:first').fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $(this).appendTo('.featured');
        }).first().fadeIn(2000);
    }, 10000);
});/*]]>*/
</script>
```

```css
  .featured > div {
   position: absolute !important;
width:1170px;
margin-top:0px !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featured">
<div id=one> <img id="demo" src="http://bwa-blog.de/bwacam2/ipcam.jpg" style="border: 1px solid #BABABA;"> </div>
<div id=one> <img id="demo" src="http://bwa-blog.de/bwacam2/ipcam.jpg" style="border: 1px solid #BABABA;"> </div>
```